# Does "I went to school at 7 am" mean I started going to school at 7 am or I arrived school at 7 am?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I feel like "**I went to school at 7 am**" means I started waking out of my house at 7 am and then was on my way to school. Maybe, I would arrive at school in 15 minutes at 7:15 am.

However, chatgpt says "**I went to school at 7 am**" might mean both "**started going**" or "**arrived**" depending on the situation or context.

But, I feel like "**I went to school at 7 am**" tends to say I started going then I arrived, but I am not sure.

Does "**I went to school at 7 am**" mean I started going to school at 7 am or I arrived school at 7 am?

Comment: It depends on the context and could mean either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means to you what it means to a native English speaker. We'd need clarity.

We can specify by saying things like:

- I **left** for school at 8am
- I **got** to school at 9pm

There are occasions where it might be tacit whether a person means departure or arrival times. For example, if said you went to the movies (cinema) "at 9pm" it *might* be assumed that was the time the movie started, but that isn't a certainty, so if you want to be clear, be specific.